# How to count with time interval as parameter in graphite?

Tags: graphite

We have a login/logout event when user login to the system:

```
2019/1/24 10:01 user1 login
2019/1/24 10:02 user2 login
2019/1/24 10:03 user1 logout
2019/1/24 10:11 user1 login
2019/1/24 10:13 user1 logout
2019/1/24 11:01 user1 login
```

Can we count total user login event that takes time interval as parameter, such as 10 mins, 30 mins, 1 hr? Is it possible to do the chart in graphite?

ex: in 30 mins, user1 login event is counted only 1 time, but actually user1 login 2 times in 10:00 ~ 10:30

```
user1  2
user2  1

total number of login event count: 3
```

ex: in 10 mins

```
user1  3
user2  1

total number of login event count: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [summarize or smartSummarize](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.summarize).

```
summarize(seriesList, intervalString, func='sum', alignToFrom=False)
```

> Summarize the data into interval buckets of a certain size.
>
> By default, the contents of each interval bucket are summed together. This is useful for counters where each increment represents a discrete event and retrieving a “per X” value requires summing all the events in that interval.